# Triggering a pipeline from the circleCI web app - can your provide placeholder text or pre-populated arguments?

Tags: continuous-integration, pipeline, circleci, circleci-workflows

When triggering a pipeline from the web UI, you're faced with a modal where you must provide the parameters that are needed as per your design of a certain workflow.

I have this trigger working as expected, however, I need to provide four arguments here, and though I know them, this is difficult for anyone else who didn't set them up to know/remember.

I've attached a screenshot showing the trigger pipeline modal. Is there any way I can pre-populate the modal either with placeholders, guide text or just default arguments to make this process easier for other engineers?

[image: circleci trigger pipeline modal]